# Why is my docker container not executing my cron job?

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, cron

I have a `node` script that I want to run periodically so I created the following `Dockerfile` to run it from a `cron` task:

```
FROM node:8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

# ensure the node packages are installed in the image
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json . 
RUN npm install

# copy the node task to working directory
COPY db-update.js .

# copy the script which will start cron to the working directory
COPY startcron.sh .

# copy the cron task to the cond.d directory
COPY crontask /etc/cron.d/crontask

# give execution rights on the cron job and script
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontask && chmod 777 ./startcron.sh

# apply the cron job
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/crontask

# create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# execute the command in the foreground
CMD /usr/src/app/startcron.sh
```

In `startcron.sh` bash script I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

printenv | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/export \1/g' > /tmp/env.sh

echo 'Starting cron' # <- ONLY THIS APPEARS IN MY CONTAINER LOGS
cron -f
```

I needed to create `/tmp/env.sh` to export the environmental variables my `node` script requires. This script should then start `cron` in the foreground. My `crontask` should "source" those environmental variables and run my `node` script. If I have set up everything correctly I expect to see the output from my node script in the logs of my Docker container.

```
# ┌───────────── minute (0 - 59)
# │ ┌───────────── hour (0 - 23)
# │ │ ┌───────────── day of month (1 - 31)
# │ │ │ ┌───────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ │ │ ┌───────────── day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday to Saturday;
# │ │ │ │ │                                       7 is also Sunday on some systems)
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# * * * * *  command to execute
# DOES THIS COMMAND EXECUTE SUCCESSFULLY, IF NOT WHY NOT?
*/5 * * * * . /tmp/env.sh /usr/local/bin/node /usr/src/app/db-update.js > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
# need to leave an empty line
```

This is a snippet from my node script:

```
const sftpclient = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fs = require('fs');

console.log('now executing db-update');
const IN_PRODUCTION = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false);
console.log('what is node env: ', process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log('what is env: ', process.env);
```

When I run this container, however, the only output I am seeing in my container logs is the echo command from my bash script "Starting Cron". I don't see any output from the node script but the container continues to run. How can I ensure that the `node` script runs or that the container fails if it doesn't?

Comment: [maybe useful](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your life much more easier I would recommend to change strategy to use simple infinite loop with sleep instead of cron

so in CMD just place
`while true; sleep 300; execute-node-program || exit 1; done`

In such strategy:

1. You have all output of your node program in docker logs
2. Container will fail if your program fail

It will be hard to achieve that by using cron as you will need probably to place systemd for 2 processes:

1. One process for cron
2. Second process to observe what is node program output and kill systemd if needed, print logs, etc. <--- that sounds really bad

Edit:

So to give you idea how to deal with killing your container when cron job fails:

1. Start your container with `--init` flag e.g. docker run --init... - that's really important and will allow you to kill main container's process from within container
2. Use similar crontab record: `*/5 * * * * bash -c "/tmp/env.sh && /usr/local/bin/node /usr/src/app/db-update.js || pkill -9 -f cron" > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2`

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I thought I'd might have solved the problem by executing cron in the foreground (cron -f) and sending the output to the console with the following: `/usr/src/app/db-update.js > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2`. I've seen some posts online where others have implemented parts of what I've done. I like your solution, but just feel I'm almost there with using `cron` and would really like to figure out where I've gone wrong before i give up.

Comment: Thankyou. How would I source the necessary environmental variables and run the node script if I modify my crontask as you have specified?

Comment: I adjusted it to your case :)

Comment: Thanks so much! It's complaining about permission denied but at least I can see cron is running and stopping the container with an error which I can detect. Thanks for your help :)